# Using What3Words addresses for 911 addressing in US?

Tags: united-states, address, emergency-services, what3words

In the US 911 districts spend a lot of money creating rural addresses for their emergency dispatch systems.

Over the past few years I've worked with several districts implementing tools that assign addresses to "structures" based on a distance along a linear feature (e.g. a road).  With the adoption of 911, rural addresses based on postal route and box numbers have been converted to a street and house (or structure) number.  This [can be complicated.](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=687192)

I've been told by these agencies that they are following procedures prescribed by [NENA](http://www.nena.org/?).

I searched for mention of What3Words in the [final report](http://www.nena.org/resource/resmgr/Standards/NADSummitReport_Final.pdf) from [NENA's National Address Database Summit](http://www.nena.org/?page=NAD), but found nothing. (Perhaps being sponsored by the Department of Transportation steers them toward road oriented addressing systems.)

*At first glance it appears W3W might be easier to maintain than systems relying on linear features.*

Has anyone used What3Words for 911 rural addressing in the US?

If so, please post a link to a whitepaper describing how it was done.

Comment: The answer will either be "Yes" or "No" (or possibly some of each)

Comment: Sounds like a huge liability!

Comment: @Midavalo I'm looking for something like a whitepaper. Granted, I don't see anything in the [NENA standards](https://www.nena.org/?page=Standards), so maybe it'll never happen.

Answer (score 3):

Some platforms and organisations are using it for first response and security from the World Humanitarian Summit to SuperBowl50 - http://what3words.com/using-what3words/emergency-response/

We have not discussed with the NENA.

We are also available in http://what3words.com/esri

Full disclosure: I work at what3words.